# chrome.browserAction.setpopup for safari

Tags: safari, popover

What is the equivalent statement for chrome.browserAction.setpopup in safari api.  For instance, when I fire a 'click' event I use chrome.browserAction.setpopup = "index.html";.  How would I go about doing this in safari.  The docs are ambiguous in their explanation and just state that it can be done.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to accomplish the same thing in safari, we need to be able to get the extension toolbar object and the popover object.  Getting the objects requires knowing their position in their respective arrays of safari.extension.toolbarItems and safari.extension.popovers.  Accomplish this by using console log until you find the correct position for each.  Then for example,

```
 var toolbar = safari.extension.toolbarItems[0];
 var myPopOver = safari.extension.popovers[2];
```

Completing the assignment with toolbar.popover = myPopOver;.  First time posting to stackoverflow, I'll edit this later to separate the code from its explanation.